# Which rewaya has the shortest madd?

Tags: quran, qiraat

My mother is unable to recite some verses without taking a gap to breath every 5 or 6 words. To make reciting easier for her, which rewaya (among the 7 mutawatir qira'at) is the easiest to recite, in other words, which one has the shortest madd?

Note: Hadr (fast) is too fast for her default recitation, so tadweer (medium) is her default.

Comment: Each of the riwayat has different kinds of madd Warsh has AFAIK the largest amount of madd mushba'a (6 signs) while in Qalun is considered as much easier.

Comment: You mean Qalun has the shortest madd?

Comment: There's no simple answer because the length of madd vary between several cases. You can't answer this by default. Because in some cases even in Qalun a 6 sign long madd could regarded as necessary.